# Stylus doesn't compile array items

Tags: css, stylus

I have following .styl file:

```
li
  background-color: rgba(#fff, .3)

  siz = 10px 70px 30px 50px 60px 20px 90px 25px 40px 30px
  deg = 45deg 45deg 45deg 45deg 45deg 45deg 45deg 45deg 45deg 45deg
  pos = 50px 120px 150px 170px 220px 250px 270px 320px 370px 420px

  for i in (1..10)
    &:nth-child(i)
      width: siz[i]
      height: siz[i]
      left: pos[i]
      transform: translateY(100px) rotate(deg[i])
```

But Stylus doesn't compile this code because of ParseError. How can I get the desired result?

Comment: Are you sure you have mentioned your variable names correctly? It should be `wid[i]` and not `siz[i]` right? :D

Comment: I made typo when creating the question, but .styl file hasn't typo, so problem isn't solved

Comment: Ok, there is another error. This error wouldn't classify as a typo, so I will post as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem now is with the selector as the proper interpolation syntax (of wrapping variables within `{}`) is not used. Modify the code like below and it should work fine.

Also note that the array's are zero based whereas the `nth-child` selectors are one based and so the array indexes should be used as `i - 1`.

```
li
  background-color: rgba(#000, .3) /* changed color just for the demo */

  siz = 10px 70px 30px 50px 60px 20px 90px 25px 40px 30px
  deg = 45deg 45deg 45deg 45deg 45deg 45deg 45deg 45deg 45deg 45deg
  pos = 50px 120px 150px 170px 220px 250px 270px 320px 370px 420px

  for i in (1..10)
    &:nth-child({i}) /* note the change here */
      width: siz[i - 1] /* note the change to index */
      height: siz[i - 1] /* note the change to index */
      left: pos[i - 1] /* note the change to index */
      transform: translateY(100px) rotate(deg[i - 1]) /* note the change to index */
```

[CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gMrxWL?editors=1100)